# Unity Switching between gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, getter-setter

I've got weird issue with my project, I'm trying to change between 2 gameobjects -villager to werewolf (both are children of the same empty gameobject) by pressing a key. for some reason it switching only one time and "stuck" at werewolf gameobject without switching back to villager. it's the second time I'm trying to handle the getter/setter.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class WerewolfTransform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject villager;
    public GameObject wereWolf;
    public bool isWerewolf;

    private void Awake()
    {
        villager.SetActive(true);
        wereWolf.SetActive(false);
    }

    public bool getIsWereWolf
    {
        set
        {
            if (isWerewolf != value)
            {
                isWerewolf = value;
                villager.SetActive(false);
                wereWolf.SetActive(true);
                
            }
            else 
            {
                villager.SetActive(true);
                wereWolf.SetActive(false);
            }
        }

        get
        {
            return isWerewolf;
        }
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        Transformation();
    }

    public void Transformation()
    {
      
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
        {
            wereWolf.transform.position = villager.transform.position;

            getIsWereWolf = !getIsWereWolf;
        } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well whenever you change the value the first case kicks in and you hard set

```
villager.SetActive(false);
wereWolf.SetActive(true);
```

no matter what value you are actually changing it to.

You would rather do it like e.g.

```
public bool getIsWereWolf
{
    set
    {
        isWerewolf = value;
        villager.SetActive(!isWerewolf);
        wereWolf.SetActive(isWerewolf);
    }

    get => isWerewolf;
}
```

To be sure to have a consistent initial state I would then also use it in `Awake`

```
private void Awake()
{
    getIsWerewolf = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks!
And I did something very similar to what u have suggested and it worked!
Ill posted what I've done ( the bool didnt worked as i wanted to I went for another direction)

```css
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class WerewolfTransform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject villager;
    public GameObject wereWolf;
    //public bool isWerewolf;
    public int formSwitch;

    private void Awake()
    {
        villager.SetActive(true);
        wereWolf.SetActive(false);
        formSwitch = 1;
    }

  
    private void Update()
    {
        Transformation();
    }

    public void Transformation()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T) && formSwitch == 1)
        {

            villager.SetActive(false);
            wereWolf.SetActive(true);
            formSwitch = 2;
            wereWolf.transform.position = villager.transform.position;
            wereWolf.transform.rotation = villager.transform.rotation;
        }

        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T) && formSwitch == 2)
        {

            villager.SetActive(true);
            wereWolf.SetActive(false);
            formSwitch = 1;
            villager.transform.position = wereWolf.transform.position;
            villager.transform.rotation = wereWolf.transform.rotation;


        }
    }
}
```